# Any auto solution for ISDEV fatal error -1014 due to target release folder pointed by win explorer?

Tags: installshield, windows-explorer

My installshield project build gave such error:

> "ISDEV : fatal error -1014: Cannot rename directory ***\Release to
>   ***\Release.Bak.  Windows Explorer or a DOS prompt may be pointing to a subfolder of the release output folder (Disk1) or to the Interm
>   folder, locking it. Change the current directory. Close any open files
>   in the Disk1 folder. Close Msidb.exe if it is open."

The reason is because before I started the build I got a win explorer opened which was pointed to that release folder. And somehow ISDEV consider this as locking the folder, so it refused to proceed with the renaming.

Now, is there a way, like add some sort of script, to forcefully close all opened win explorer instance to release the socalled "lock" before the build script starts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old thread, but the problem is still around.

It seems the error is nothing to do with another process having the folder locked.  I think InstallShield is fighting with itself by trying to rename a folder where IT still has some files open.  That's why many of the traditional approaches such as closing explorer and even rebooting sometimes don't work.

I found a fairly simple solution is to delete the folder tree \Express from the Setup project folder before doing a build.  InstallShield just recreates it and everything is OK because the rename was not needed.

Comment: where do you find the \Express folder tree?

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been around as long as I remember working in my first IntallShield.

Don't try to beat the locking. Just make sure you don't keep explorer open on the release folder prior to the build. You can however navigate to its parent folder or better yet: define a [post build distribution event](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/InstallShield2011/ReleaseGridPostBuildTab.htm#wp1205780).

Answer (score 0):

The way I have found to remove that folder is to put something like this in the pre-build events:

```
RD fullPath\Express /S /Q
```

Because InstallShield project does not have the same properties as other projects do, I have inserted that in the Pre-build events at the properties of the main project of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, just closed InstallShield and re-opened it, worked like a charm.

Comment: Good ! You are right, tried this also and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, fixed it by Ending this task "InstallShield (R) 64-bit Setup Engine"

[image]